# match the passwords

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a piece of code for the password match. I want to verify every character with password field while typing in confirm password field.

```
    var npass = $('#password');
    var rpass = $('#confirmpassword');
    if( npass.val() != rpass.val() ) {
        Val.errors = true;
        Val.showerrors = true;
        $("#confirmpasswordError").html("must match");
        $("#confirmpasswordError").addClass('error-Yes-msg').show();
        $("#confirmpassword").addClass('error-input');
        return false;
    } else {
        $("#confirmpasswordError").removeClass('error-msg').html('');
        $("#confirmpassword").removeClass('error-input');
    }
```

Comment: Is there some error in the code? Are you not getting the result you expect? What are you seeing?

Comment: Try posting on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) and then linking that to your question.

Answer (score 2):

You've got it. You just need to bind it to the keyup/keydown event of the boxes.

**Live Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/FPNBe/2/

```
$('#password, #confirmpassword').keyup(function() { checkPass(); } );


function checkPass(){
    var rpass = $('#confirmpassword').val();
    var npass = $('#password').val();
    if(npass!= rpass) {
        //Val.errors = true;
        //Val.showerrors = true;
        $("#confirmpasswordError").html("must match");
        //$("#confirmpasswordError").addClass('error-Yes-msg').show();
        //$("#confirmpassword").addClass('error-input');
        return false;
    } else {
        $("#confirmpasswordError").html("match!");
        //$("#confirmpasswordError").removeClass('error-msg').html('');
        //$("#confirmpassword").removeClass('error-input');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you should just bind this code to `$("#confirmpassword").keydown()`

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very vague. Is there some error in the code? Are you not getting the result you expect? What are you seeing? Provided your password fields really have the `id` values (not names) "password" and "confirmpassword", and provided they're `input` elements or similar, then fundamentally that should work, except:

1. You're returning `false` when they don't match, but not returning `true` when they do (at least, not in your quoted code). So if this is in a function you're calling, and you're checking the return value, you're going to see a falsey value either way.
2. You're adding the class `error-Yes-msg` when they don't match, but not removing it when they do (you're removing `error-msg` instead).
3. You're not clearing `Val.errors` and `Val.showerrors` when they match.

Addressing those and doing a bit of tidying up:

```
var npass = $('#password');
var rpass = $('#confirmpassword');
var match = npass.val() == rpass.val();
Val.errors = Val.showerrors = !match;

if(match) {
    $("#confirmpasswordError").removeClass('error-Yes-msg').html('');
    $("#confirmpassword").removeClass('error-input');
} else {
    $("#confirmpasswordError")
        .html("must match")
        .addClass('error-Yes-msg').show();
    $("#confirmpassword").addClass('error-input');
}
return match;
```

Answer (score 0):

It would seem like `.keyup()/.keydown()` would work, but its kinda tricky sometimes. So, try [this plugin](http://www.zurb.com/playground/jquery-text-change-custom-event) from Zurb. It works like a charm.

Now, your code should be something like this:

```
var npass = $('#password');
var rpass = $('#confirmpassword');

rpass.bind('textchange', function (event, previousText) {
    if( npass.val() != rpass.val() ) {
        Val.errors = true;
        Val.showerrors = true;
        $("#confirmpasswordError").html("must match");
        $("#confirmpasswordError").addClass('error-Yes-msg').show();
        $("#confirmpassword").addClass('error-input');
        return false;
    } else {
        $("#confirmpasswordError").removeClass('error-msg').html('');
        $("#confirmpassword").removeClass('error-input');
    }
});
```